# PyQtGraph: Customized Color Map

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, colormap

I have some GPS position data and I need to plot them coloring the line in-between with a different color guided by speed value.

Then I need to create a color map to give a legend to the user.

I can't find any tutorial or example using line plot, only with ImageView or scatterPlot, for the line color I manage with a RGB tuple list with color scale.
I don't know how to create the legend, to me it can even be a 'static' image only show color and value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suggest looking at the documentation for the legend (https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/legenditem.html) or looking at the provided examples in `pyqtgraph.examples`, and doing the colors yourself, with the color keyword argument.